# Литература об ООП в Delphi, FreePascal

Tags: delphi, ооп, книги, freepascal

Подскажите книгу про ООП в этих языках или хотя бы книгу про эти языки, в которых есть глава, называющаяся не "основы ООП", а просто "ООП". Статью тоже можно.

Например. Вопрос про то, как использовать property? Точнее про методы, которые устанавливаются как сеттеры и геттеры. Как указать на параметр метода, через который и нужно, чтобы происходило чтение или запись?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищи нетленные бестселлеры Марко Кэнту ("Delphi 7" его у меня настольная книга). Очень рекомендую также Тексейру и Пачеко.